# Perl: Match exact word from tab-delimited file

Tags: regex, perl, csv

I have a tab-delimited file (containing 2 columns) in the following format:

```
ABA-1 (tab)           CDF@
ABA-1 (tab)           EFG
ZYA (tab)             ABA-1 this
EFG that this (tab)   ZYA
```

I want to match only /EFG/ and not /EFG that this/. Similarly, I want to only match /ABA-1/ and not /ABA-1 this/.

The following pattern doesn't work:

```
$line=~ /^(\w*\-?\w*\@?)\t*(\w*\-?\w*\@?)$/
```

I have tried using word boundaries (\b) but it doesn't work either.

Any ideas on how to tackle this issue? Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So you want to match all characters till you find a space? Like `CDF@` also?

Comment: What about `$%^2 this` after the Tab?

Comment: Yes I want to match till I find a space.

Comment: @RohitJain: I didn't understand your second comment.

Comment: Well `fba#$@! thsi (tab) $%^ asf` -> So what do you want to match in this string? -> `fba#$@!`  and  `$%^`?

Answer (score 3):

Your regex doesn't work for a couple of reasons. Firstly your tab can't be optional, otherwise the line won't be split properly. Secondly, there is nothing in your pattern to account for the possible characters *after* the parts that you want to match, i.e. nothing that matches `that this`.

You can solve the first by adding `.*?` after each capture (or, for the second capture, just removing the trailing `$` anchor). The second problem is fixed just by changing `\t*` to `\t`.

This modification works with your sample data

```
$line =~ /^(\w*\-?\w*\@?).*?\t(\w*\-?\w*\@?).*?$/
```

but it isn't very pretty!

It looks like you just want all strings of non-space characters directly after a tab or the beginning of the line

This program encodes that idea as a regex

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = (
  "ABA-1\tCDF@",
  "ABA-1\tEFG", 
  "ZYA\tABA-1 this",
  "EFG that this\tZYA",
);

for (@data) {
  my @fields = /(?:^|\t)(\S+)/g;
  print "@fields\n";
}
```

**output**

```
ABA-1 CDF@
ABA-1 EFG
ZYA ABA-1
EFG ZYA
```

Answer (score 1):

This will match two words (containing no spaces) separated by a single tab on a line:

```
$line=~ /^(\w+)\t(\w+)$/
```

Update: that will exclude any lines that have something like "ABA this".  However, maybe you want to capture just the ABA out of "ABA this". This would do that for you:

```
$line=~ /^([A-Z]+)[^\t]*\t([A-Z]+)/
```

**Update:** here is a new pattern for the new requirements.  It matches the first non-white-space portion in each column.

```
$line=~ /^([^\s]+).*\t\s*([^\s]+)/
```

Comment: Please look at the edited input file. I have changed it to make it more similar to my original file.

Comment: Your updated code doesn't work with CDF@ (line 1, 2nd column) and ABA-1 this (line 3, 2nd column).

Comment: @zock, I have tested it, and the matches return "CDF@" and "ABA-1", respectively, in those cases.  If you aren't getting those results, then there is some other issue with your code, or your file is not quite as described. For example, if you had a tab character after the second column, that would cause it to fail.

Answer (score 1):

```
$line=~ /^(\w+)[^\t]*\t(\w+).*$/
```

This will capture only the first word before and after the `tab`.

**UPDATE**: - If you want to match `any non-space` character before the first space, then you can try this pattern: -

```
my $line = "ABA-1\tCDF@";
my $line1 = "ZYA \t  ABA-1 this";

if ($line=~ /^([^\s]+)[^\t]*\t\s*([^\s]+).*$/) {    
    print "$1 $2";
}

if ($line=~ /^([^\s]+)[^\t]*\t\s*([^\s]+).*$/) {    
    print "$1 $2";
}
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
ABA-1 CDF@
ZYA ABA-1
```

Comment: This won't work for the lines that only have a single word on each side of the tab.  It would break up "ABA" in the first line into "AB" and "A", for example and only return "AB" as the match.

Comment: Please look at the edited input file. I have changed it to make it more similar to my original file.

Comment: Well according to the pattern you provided, I want to match 34%! (tab) %^#.

Comment: Your updated code doesn't work with CDF@ (line 1, 2nd column) and ABA-1 this (line 3, 2nd column).

Comment: In 2nd column, there can be space like: ABA-1(space)this.

Comment: The double backslashes prevent your patterns matching the tab character: you want just `\t`. Also there is no need to capture the tab - you know what it is after all!

Comment: @Borodin Well, I tried it in `Eclipse` but, it doesn't matches `\t`, but `\\t`

Comment: @RohitJain, the reason you were having trouble matching tabs is that your example code above uses single-quoted strings.  So your test data does not really have tabs; it literally has `'\t'`.  That is why you needed a double backslash to match it. Fix this by using double quotes for your test data.

Comment: @dan1111 Ah! Thanks dan. I was almost lost there.. :)

Comment: @Borodin Can you please remove your downvote, if the current pattern is ok?